# How storage space is allocated in Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using Minikube to bootstrap a Kubernetes cluster on my local machine (for learning purposes). I am in Windows platform. Minikube is installed on C drive. It's actually low on disk space due to some personal files and other Softwares. According to [Minikube documentations](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/), it requires a 20GB of disk space for its VM. However, when I try to bootstrap the Kubernetes cluster sometimes booting up fails stating low disk space. But disk space is available in my other drives.

By default on which drive, Minikube allocates its space? Installed location? Is there any way to specify on which drive Minikube allocates its 20GB space?

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I am using hyperv as my VM driver

Comment: Try this: https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-change-default-vhd-location/ and let me know if helped or not

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, disk allocation is done by the driver which is used to create the VM. In my case I was using hyperv as my VM driver, so I used following steps. (Your steps may slightly vary according to your Windows OS version - I am using Windows 10)

Start ---> Hyper-V manager ---> Hyper-V settings ---> Change the default folder to store virtual hard disk files

You can find detailed illustration in [here](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-change-default-vhd-location/)